# Flexbox and SVG content

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

```
  <body>
    <div class="home">
      <div class="title-header">
        <div>HEADER</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="left-pane">
          <div class="content">
            <!-- SVG overflows the container on resize -->
            <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
            </svg>   

            <!-- Using a Div instead works great!
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white">
              </div> -->
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div id="rightpane" class="right-pane">
          <button onClick="toggleSize()">Resize</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div>FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.title-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.left-pane {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
}

.right-pane {
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  width: 350px;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  &.min {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 810px;
  left: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Example is here: https://codepen.io/johnny4111/pen/ZEYNqyq

I have a structure as in the example, it's a container that has a left and right pane.  The right pane can be minimized programmatically.  The Left pane has an SVG set to take up 100% height and 100% width.  The left pane has flex-grow set to 1 so that it takes up 100% of the free height but should not exceed the bounds of it's parent div.

The expectation is when the right pane is minimized and the left pane expands it's width to take up the now available free space the SVG should still constrain itself to the available height (100% height) since the height has not changed, just the width.  However, in reality it overflows the div.  There is a absolute positioned footer at the bottom so you can see it overflows into that.

Any ideas what the problem is?  If I use a regular div set to 100% width, 100% height instead of an SVG it works without any issues.  The Div does not overflow it's parent.

Comment: The div does not have a defined aspect ratio that you're saying needs to be preserved. Do you want to abandon that in the SVG too, otherwise your situations are not comparable. If you do, set preserveAspectRatio="none" or if you must keep the aspect ratio does slice do what you want rather than meet?

Comment: The preserveAspectRatio will define the characteristics of the scaling - the contents should not overflow the viewport. The viewport dimensions are specified as 100% of the width and height of the containing div. In this case the SVG exceeds the viewport dimensions which is strange.  The "meet" explicitly specifies that the graphics should be scaled UNTIL it meets the height and width of the viewport, that is per the official spec.  I can't seem to understand why the spec is violated here.

Comment: setting max-height:100%; will also fix your problem